# How can I construct a Turing Machine that accepts encoding of another Turing Machine?

Tags: turing-machines, encoding-scheme

How can I construct a Turing Machine that accepts the language 
L = <'M'> which is an encoding of a Turing Machine M?

Comment: Is the question whether you can construct a TM that halts and accepts if you give it an encoded TM, and rejects otherwise, given that you have an agreed encoding scheme? Or is it given a string, can it decide whether the string could be interpreted as a TM?

Comment: What have you tried?  What are your thoughts?  What self-study have you done?  Do you know how to write a program in Python (or your favorite programming language) to do that?  We expect you to make a significant effort before asking here, and to explain in the question what you've tried and what you're stuck on.

Comment: It depends if you have any coding restrictions. If you have not (so any coding is acceptable) accept ∑*.

Comment: @Byakuya Didn't I already say that?

Comment: Well, that's why I did not answer the question, just tried to point that it *does depend* if there are some encoding restrictions, which you did not write about. I upvoted your answer anyway, and I believe stack is a place where any suggestion towards the solution is fine. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Choose a coding of Turing machines such that every string is a valid coding. Then, your Turing machine just needs to accept $\Sigma^*$, which is trivial.